# Do I have to buy Minecraft java edition if I have purchased MCPE?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I already purchased MCPE and now I want to play Minecraft java edition. Do I have to purchase Minecraft java edition? Or can I download it for free.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you must pay for Java Edition, as they are slightly different games. Plus
Bedrock is way cheaper.

Comment: they're the same price, like $28 each

Comment: Not really, he said he has P.E., not console. If he had console, then maybe, but P.E. P.E. only costs about $7, so yeah.

Comment: @Nicholar I thought he meant Winodws 10 edition okay